# Inserting records into DatedConversionRate from Apex with the REST API fails with an odd response

Tags: apex, rest-api, multi-currency

With advanced currency management enabled, I'm inserting new dated currency data with a form post to this URL: `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v51.0/composite/tree/DatedConversionRate/'`

Here's the body of the message:

```json
 {
    "records": [
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refAUD"
          },
          "IsoCode": "AUD",
          "ConversionRate": "1.31458",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refCAD"
          },
          "IsoCode": "CAD",
          "ConversionRate": "1.27856",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refCHF"
          },
          "IsoCode": "CHF",
          "ConversionRate": "0.897860",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refDKK"
          },
          "IsoCode": "DKK",
          "ConversionRate": "6.17871",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refEUR"
          },
          "IsoCode": "EUR",
          "ConversionRate": "0.830744",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refGBP"
          },
          "IsoCode": "GBP",
          "ConversionRate": "0.732043",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refMXN"
          },
          "IsoCode": "MXN",
          "ConversionRate": "20.1393",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refNOK"
          },
          "IsoCode": "NOK",
          "ConversionRate": "8.60171",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refSEK"
          },
          "IsoCode": "SEK",
          "ConversionRate": "8.39861",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       },
       {
          "attributes":
          {
             "type": "DatedConversionRate",
             "referenceId": "refZAR"
          },
          "IsoCode": "ZAR",
          "ConversionRate": "14.9536",
          "StartDate": "2021-2-2"
       }
    ]
 }
```

This results in the following response: `[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]`

I'm executing the code anonymously for testing purposes.  What could be causing the error?

Comment: Your payload uses [Composite Tree API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm), the endpoint is different. The current API version is v50 or v51, depending on your org. v28 is 2013.

Comment: Thanks @identigral, I've updated the endpoint URL as you suggest but the response is identical.  The updated endpoint ends with: /services/data/v51.0/composite/tree/DatedConversionRate/

Comment: Try v50.0, your org may not be on v51 yet.

Comment: That was the solution.  Thank you!
If you want to answer the question, I'll accept it.